# how to check the dynamic values using if condition in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried to validate the user input from the contenteditable in jquery. I don't know exactly where I made the mistake. Please advise.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#p28-textid39").hide();
  $(".result").click(function() {
    $("#p28-textid39").show();
    var data_answer = $(this).attr("data-answer");
    var content = $(this).text();
    if (content == data_answer) {
      alert("correct");
    } else {
      alert("incorrect");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure id="bodyimage">
  <img alt="" src="images/page0028.jpg" />
</figure>
<div id="parent-p28">
  <p><span class="styleid2" id="p28-textid12">line is to write an ____________________.</span>
  </p>
  <p><span class="styleid9" id="p28-textid39">answer</span>
  </p>
  <div style="position:absolute;left:348px;top:278px;" class="act1">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="txt" data-answer="answer" contenteditable="true"></td>
        <td><span class="show">&#160;</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="opacity:0;">
        <td>____________________</td>
        <td><span class="show">&#160;</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="result" data-act="1" style="position:absolute;left:65px;top:173px;width:170px;height:125px;cursor:pointer;border:1px solid;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add trim and convert both to lowercase to make sure they are same. having an extra space and uppercase or lowercase could be one reason for comparing text to fail

Comment: where user is going to write an answer?  in `<td>` or in `<div class="result"`?

Comment: user can insert the answer in <td>

Comment: then content value is wrong from selector side they will not be the same.

Comment: But you're trying to get the answer from `$(this).text()`, and `this` is the `.result` DIV.

Comment: @amjs - you mean to say that user will put answer in `<td class="txt" data-answer="answer" contenteditable="true"></td>` and same element have reference answer to compare with. am I correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding user will be writing answer in `<td class="txt" data-answer="answer" contenteditable="true"></td>` which contains the reference answer to compare with; you may try below code:

```
$(function() {
  $("#p28-textid39").hide();
  $(".result").click(function() {
    $("#p28-textid39").show();

    var sibAnwserDiv = $(this).prevAll(".act1").first(); //grab the wrapper Div in which <table> is present
    var targetTD = $(sibAnwserDiv).find("td.txt");

    var data_answer = targetTD.data("answer"); //get the reference answer
    var content = $.trim(data_answer.text()); //get the answer entered by user

    if (content == data_answer) {
      alert("correct");
    } else {
      alert("incorrect");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

case with incorrect use of 'this'

```js
$(function() {
  $("#p28-textid39").hide();
  $(".result").click(function() {
    $("#p28-textid39").show();
    var data_answer = $(".txt").attr("data-answer");
    var content = $("#p28-textid39").text();
    if (content == data_answer) {
      alert("correct");
    } else {
      alert("incorrect");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure id="bodyimage">
  <img alt="" src="images/page0028.jpg" />
</figure>
<div id="parent-p28">
  <p><span class="styleid2" id="p28-textid12">line is to write an ____________________.</span>
  </p>
  <p><span class="styleid9" id="p28-textid39">answer</span>
  </p>
  <div style="position:absolute;left:348px;top:278px;" class="act1">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="txt" data-answer="answer" contenteditable="true"></td>
        <td><span class="show">&#160;</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="opacity:0;">
        <td>____________________</td>
        <td><span class="show">&#160;</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="result" data-act="1" style="position:absolute;left:65px;top:173px;width:170px;height:125px;cursor:pointer;border:1px solid;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you explain what you meant with answer plz?

Comment: if the static value working fine. I want to get the values from "<td>____________________</td>" this elements when the user insert.

Comment: @amjs You need to give that element an ID so you can use `$("#id").text()` to get the contents.

Comment: is there a way to find the value <td>______</td> without using any id/class?

Comment: can you use class 'txt' ?

Comment: if you can add another data attr thien loop to find it $("td[data-column='"+dynamic+"']")

Answer (score 0):

your code most be like this

```
$(function() {
    $("#p28-textid39").hide();
    $(".result").click(function() {
        $("#p28-textid39").show();
        var data_answer = $("#p28-textid39").attr("data-answer");
        var content = $(".txt").text();
        if (content == data_answer) {
            alert("correct");
        } else {
            alert("incorrect");
        }
    });
});
```

line 6 and 7 most be change